# Positioning of overlays in documentclass standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, standalone, shift

I use the following code to overlay FIGURE2 onto FIGURE1:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{FIGURE1.pdf}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
    \node at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{FIGURE2.pdf}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In `\documentclass{beamer}` this works fine, but with `\documentclass{standalone}` the positioning option `current page.center` does not place the node in the center of FIGURE1. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The point of `standalone` is usually to crop the resulting page. If you just want to pictures on top of each other simply use one TikZ picture.

Answer (score 2):

The page concept in `standalone` is a bit special. In contrast to other classes, it is not a fixed reference point, but will adapt to the content of the document.

To get the same behaviour as in beamer, you could use the `beamer` option: `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`. This will give you a fixed page where you can place your images, just like the frames you know from beamer.

### Different approach:

Maybe easier: place both images in the same tikz picture

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
  \begin{scope}[overlay]
      \node at (current bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, which works fine in the simple problem of my MWE. However, I would prefer a solution in which FIGURE1.pdf defines the dimensions of the resulting pdf, and the tikzpicture environment can be used to add stuff without affecting the dimensions. In principle my code works already, the only annoying thing is that I can't get the \node at (0,0) to be placed in the center of the figure.

Comment: If you don't want to your additions to affect the page size, you can still use the `overlay` option for them, see e.g. my edited answer.

Comment: I'm not on a PC right now but be aware of `inner sep`s (and also `outer sep`s for an extra level of nit-pick) that adds padding around the node contents and might make positioning elements a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. I found a partial solution for my problem: If, in my original MWE, I drop `shift={(current page.center)}` then the `node at (0,0)` is always at the south east corner of FIGURE1, independent of the dimensions of FIGURE1.pdf. Still, I would prefer a shift command that puts the `node at (0,0)`in the center of FIGURE1. I tried using `shift={(-.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight)}` but this does not work, because the variables for width and height are not reflecting the true dimensions of the document.